# Hover on parent to trigger transform property

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to use a hover effect to transform my second arrow `#arrowDown2` to go down to show both arrows. I am wanting the hover to trigger on `arrowDownWrap`.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
#blue {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: blue;
}  
#arrowDownWrap {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 120px;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);transform: translate(-50%,0);
 cursor: pointer;
}
#arrowDownWrapInner {
 position: relative;
 bottom: 40px;
}
#arrowDown, #arrowDown2 {
    border: solid #FFF;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);transform: rotate(45deg);
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
}
#arrowDownWrap:hover #arrowDown2 {
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg), translate(0, 40px);transform: rotate(45deg), translate(0, 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <div id="arrowDownWrap">
    <div id="arrowDownWrapInner">
      <i id="arrowDown"></i>
      <i id="arrowDown2"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: don't separate multiple `transform`s with comma, just put them next to each other like `transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 40px);`

Comment: To the close voter - doing something wrong is not a valid case for the "typographical error" close reason. Only use that reason for errors in transcription and typing, **not** for intentional programming that happens to be invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To specify multiple CSS [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) properties, no comma is necessary.
Just list them one after another.

For example:

```css
transform: rotate(45deg) translate(0, 40px);
```

Working example:

```css
#blue {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
}

#arrowDownWrap {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100px;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#arrowDownWrapInner {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 20px;
}

#arrowDown,
#arrowDown2 {
  border: solid #FFF;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  display: block;
  padding: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
}

#arrowDownWrap:hover #arrowDown2 {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 50px) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translate(0, 50px) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="blue">
  <div id="arrowDownWrap">
    <div id="arrowDownWrapInner">
      <i id="arrowDown"></i>
      <i id="arrowDown2"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know why the arrow image is going to the left of the other arrow? I just want it to go directly underneath of the arrow.

Comment: I believe that is because the arrow is rotated after it is translated. I reversed the order.